# How to support stopPropagation in delegated event listeners

Tags: javascript, event-handling, stoppropagation, event-delegation, event-propagation

I've looked at the source code from jQuery to find out how they implemented support for `event.stopPropagation()` in delegated event listeners, i.e. `document.on(event, element...)`, but can't seem to get my own vanilla JS implementation to fully work.

I tried overriding the native `event.stopPropagation()` in my method to simply set an `event.propagationStopped` on the event itself, and looking for this when deciding if the event should propagate up to its parents.

This works when the event listener that stops propagation is attached before other ones, however it does not when it's attached in reverse order, something that does work as expected in jQuery's implementation.

```
function delegate(type, selector, callback) {
    document.addEventListener(type, function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation = function() {
            event.propagationStopped = true;
        };

        var element = event.target, found;

        while (element && element.parentNode) {
            if (element.matches(selector)) {
                callback.call(element, event);
            }

            if (!event.propagationStopped) {
                element = element.parentNode;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}


delegate('click', '.overlay', function() {
    console.log('Close overlay');
});

delegate('click', '.modal', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    console.log('Clicked inside modal, stopping propagation...');
});
```

I want the event to stop its further propagation in all event listeners regardless of the order in which they were attached, instead of the current behaviour.

Comment: IIRC, jQuery attaches only a single actual DOM event listener and stores the callbacks in data properties on the elements. Then when the DOM event fires, it does all of the propagation and sequential calling on its own.

Comment: @Bergi I was thinking about that as well, but I hope there is an easier way of doing it, since I'm not sure how to store these (don't want to attach anything to actual elements), nor how to decide in what sequence they should be called.

Comment: I'll write an answer demonstrating how to do that. Not sure whether there is a better way, I'm curious as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is only possible by doing the delegated event propagation yourself in a single event listener. In your current implementation, the second listener attached to the `document` always fires second, regardless of its selector - but when it selects a descendant of the other selector, you need it to fire first.

Here I'm collecting a list of delegated event listeners, and then iterate that for each element in your parent traversal. You could keep the list on the element itself (e.g. with symbols or a `WeakMap`), but since you only delegate on `document` I'll simply store them globally.

```
const delegatedListeners = {};

function delegate(type, selector, callback) {
    if (!delegatedListeners[type]) {
        const listeners = delegatedListeners[type] = [];
        document.addEventListener(type, function(event) {
            for (let element = event.target; element && element.parentNode; element = element.parentNode) {
                // unfortunately, event.currentTarget cannot be overwritten with element
                for (const {selector, callback} of listeners) {
                    if (element.matches(selector)) {
                        callback.call(element, event);
                    }
                }
                if (event.cancelBubble) { // a getter for the propagation stopped flag :-)
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    delegatedListeners[type].push({selector, callback});
}
```

Comment: I had no idea it could be solved with only this amount of code, and that I didn't even need to implement `stopPropagation` if simply checking the native `cancelBubble` property! I see you added an `element` argument that I believe was a mistake, because when I removed it the code started working (also you forgot an opening curly bracket in your `for ... of` loop). It works really great, thanks a lot. I also decided to add the listeners object as a subproperty of `delegate` itself, so I can export only `delegate` as an es6 module. [See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tidsoptimisten/8ezf24ho/)

Comment: @Tidsoptimisten Feel free to [suggest an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) for such obvious mistakes, thanks (I first thought of a more complicated solution installing listeners on an arbitrary `element`, before I realised you only used `document`). Btw, you still can `export function delegate` without making the listeners a property, keeping the `const delegatedListeners` variable hidden in the module scope.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise I could do that, thanks! And yeah I get the idea of being able to scope it to certain elements, might look at doing this later. And finally, that's cool, I hadn't realised either that I could export functions like that, nor that the exported function obviously still has access to those constants.